# Managed Package flow not recognizing new Picklist values in a multi-select field using a global picklist value set

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-select

Trying to work out if this is a packaging issue or a flow issue...

Install a managed package in a customer org. On creation of a Service Application record (custom object) a headless flow runs that creates a child record of the Service Application (Application Contact, also custom object). This flow takes some of the information on the related Contact Record around demographics and writes that information to the child record created as part of the headless flow.

One of the fields is a multi-select picklist whose values are determined by a Global Picklist Value Set. The issue here is that any values added to the Race Picklist Value Set **after** the package was installed are throwing errors with this process/flow automation.

> Example: Add a value "Any Race" to the picklist value set. Make sure
>   that picklist value is available to all record types on the
>   Application Contact object and on Contacts. Select the new value only
>   on a contact, try to create a Service Application, error occurs (bad
>   picklist value for restricted picklist).
>
> But if I assign the contact with both "White" (a value that existed in the
>   Managed Package) and the new value "Any Race", the Application Contact
>   record that gets created has a race value of only White. It's like the
>   Process and Flow are ignoring the new value.

If I try to do something similar with a single select picklist on both objects, it works fine...